# How do you install multiple WSO2 products?

Tags: wso2

The installation instructions are clear how to download a .zip for an individual product (e.g. ESB, Application Server, Mashup Server). But based on the OSGi component architecture, I thought it would be possible to, for example, add Mashup Server functionality to an existing install of the ESB. I've looked at the Feature Manager, and tried adding a repository (http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/3.2.4/), but have not had success.

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Seems you are using a wrong feature repo link(As ttp://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/3.2.4/ doesn't have features supported by any ESB version). Correct feature repository link depend on the product version of the ESB you use. eg - If ESB version is 4.0.3, the p2 repo link is http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/3.2.3/ . So please let us know the ESB version you use.

Comment: I found I was not able to run multiple products as there were port clashes, fortunately you can work around this with;

 - Pass the port offset to the server during startup. The following command starts the server with the default port incremented by  ./wso2server.sh -DportOffset=3 or 

 - Set the Ports section of <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml as follows:<Offset>3</Offset>


See https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Changing+the+Default+Ports+with+Offset for more details

Answer (score 8):

It's possible to install different features via the feature manager, but you have to determine the correct version of the feature compliant with the target server. For example, to install BPEL features to WSO2 ESB 4.0.2, first find the related WSO2 Carbon platform version. This can be determined by the version of $ESB-HOME/repository/components/plugins/org.wso2.carbon.core-x.x.x.jar. So if WSO2 ESB 4.0.2 is the target server, then the version of org.wso2.carbon.core jar would be 3.2.2. So the relevant BPEL feature version is 3.2.2.

You can read more about [Installing+Features](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB402/Installing+Features) and [How install the BPEL features via Feature Manager](http://ddweerasiri.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-install-bpel-features-via-feature.html).

Comment: Though with the more recent versions you will run into problems when trying to install other products as features. Unless you use more than year old builds, it probably won't work. And those older builds have their own bugs and lack of features. So you could try running multiple products side by side, configuring the admin port offset in carbon.xml. I haven't seen much info about this in documentation but from the state of the product it seems like this is the path that developers are trying to go.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to WSO2 release matrix [1] in order to match the correct version
By looking at it, you can easily find the Carbon version of any product version.

For example ESB 4.0.2 has the carbon version 3.2.2

[1] http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/