# How to install mashup feature in wso2 ESB

Tags: wso2, esb, mashup, wso2-esb

I am fairly new to WSO2.

I have a linux box with WSO2 installed. Now I would like to install the mashup feature. Is it possibel to install the mashup as an add on to ESB?

Thanks,
AP

Comment: This url provides some guidance around installing features: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690766/how-do-you-install-multiple-wso2-products).  You should be able to apply the same steps for installing the mashup feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a useful discussion on this particular topic of installing features to any carbon server by following link. [How do you install multiple WSO2 products?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690766/how-do-you-install-multiple-wso2-products)

Regards,
Prabath