# How to merge wso2 products?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I want to merge WSO2 ESB and Data Services Products to execute both of them 
on one server.
Both of them are based on Carbon framework and consists of some OSGi bundles.
Is there a simple way to do this.

Best regards.

--Seyyed Jamal

Comment: This might also help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690766/how-do-you-install-multiple-wso2-products

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can install the ESB features in the DSS or vise versa. Feature installing way is common for all the WSO2 Carbon Servers (ESB, IS, AS, DSS, BAM .....). [Here is a blog post *I wrote*](http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-install-new-feature-on-wso2.html) on installing an AS feature in IS. It is the same procedure for the ESB or DSS, find the required features, install them.

Comment: I have added the required disclosure to your link here.