# Installing WSO2 Data service server as a feature

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have installed WSO2 ESB and would like to add data services feature. However, I didn't find any reference to "Data services server" under configure->features-> available features or installed features.

Am I missing anything in configuration?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to download the full repository (unless you're behind a firewall and have problems connecting), but rather use the remote repository by entering the corresponding URL (cf. http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/). 
The DSS features compatible to your ESB are usually the ones using the same Carbon major and minor version, e.g., 4.0.x.

Thus, you won't be able to install DSS features with the latest ESB, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299294/adding-dss-features-to-esb-4-7-0-conflicting-dependencies

Comment: I guess, that is the reason I didn't find DSS installation in configuration page. This helps a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the relavent [P2-rep](http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/) according to your ESB version and then [install feature](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Installing+Features) (DSS feature) accordingly. Also pls refer [How do you install multiple WSO2 products?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9690766/2764076)